# Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php, functions, categories

My website notices that **$separator** at (#1) and **$authorpost** at (#2) are undefined variables. Although it still works.

How to fix this? I have no training in how to code, hope someone can help. Thanks very much!

```
add_filter('the_content', 'ocs_after_post');        
function ocs_after_post($content) { 

    if(is_single()){        

    $titlepost = '<a href="'.esc_url( get_the_permalink() ).'" title="'.esc_attr( get_the_title() ).'">' .get_the_title(). '</a>"';     

    $begin = '<div class="more-post-info">Do you like the poem "'.$titlepost.' by ';        

    $categories = get_the_category();       
        $count=0;       
        if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {     
        foreach( $categories as $category ) {       
        $count++;       
        if($count!=1) $separator[$count]=" — ";

(#1)$category = $separator[$count].'<a href="'.esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ).'" title="'.esc_html( $category->name ).'">' .esc_html( $category->name ).'</a>';

(#2)$authorpost .= $category;
        }

    $end = $begin.$authorpost. ' on website? If so, do not forget to share this posts to your friends and family &#9825; !</div>';
        }       
      }     
    return $content.$end;
    }
```

Comment: It just means that you need to define the variables before you do anything with them. So you should basically add `$separator = [];` and `$authorpost = '';` before the `$categories = get_the_category();`

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ! Thanks for the reply. I followed your instructions, the undefined variable notices were fixed. But a new notices appears: **Notice: Undefined offset: 1** at (#1).

Comment: That's because the `$separator[$count]` doesn't *always* exist. So when accessing items in arrays, you should always check if the item is defined; something like `$sep = isset( $separator[$count] ) ? $separator[$count] : '';` in your case. And you'd add that before the `(#1)` in the code, then use `$category = $sep.` instead of `$category = $separator[$count].`. But your question is a generic PHP question, so it should've been better asked on sites like Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ WOW, Great!!! Thank you so much, everything has been fixed. And thanks again for patiently explaining to people who don't know the code like me. Wish you a good day! : D

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. But there's another issue in the code - you should add `$end = '';` (i.e. define the `$end`) at the top of the function, before the `if(is_single()){`. :)